# Direct3DHook CapturedBitmap.ToBitmap() causes DirectX application to crash

Tags: c#, directx, screenshot

I have an application that captures a screenshot of a 32-bit DirectX application (BlueStacks) whenever it needs it. It uses Direct3DHook (http://spazzarama.com/2011/03/14/c-screen-capture-and-overlays-for-direct3d-9-10-and-11-using-api-hooks/) to get the screenshots.  It works fine, but after about 150 calls, it crashes BlueStacks (not the program that is performing the capture).

The "Load Test" button on the TestScreenshot application that comes with the Direct3DHook download does not crash BlueStacks.  So I modified the TestScreenshot application that comes with Direct3DHook to execute the simple code below and it does crash BlueStacks.  Does anybody know why the code below doesn't work as well as the "Load Test" button?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(testCapture).Start();
}
public void testCapture()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        Bitmap b = _captureProcess.CaptureInterface.GetScreenshot().CapturedBitmap.ToBitmap();
        b.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by calling Dispose() on the Screenshot object.  I'm not sure why the TestScreenshot program didn't cause a crash of BlueStacks even though it didn't Dispose() the Screenshot, but in the example above, that is what is required, like this:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       new Thread(testCapture).Start();
   }
   public void testCapture()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Screenshot s = _captureProcess.CaptureInterface.GetScreenshot();
            Bitmap b = s.CapturedBitmap.ToBitmap();
            s.Dispose();
        }
    }
```